# How to set flexible position in row / container bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap with grid,the goal is to show the same in the pic demo. In this pic demo, element photo ( green border ) seem like in a div ( col-6 ), but width of photos is reach to side of view . How can I build like that with html and css

```
 <section class="intro-project">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="./images/intro1.jpg" class="float-right" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi
        reprehenderit illum ab fugit vel enim voluptatem dicta quidem
        ratione, corporis, non molestias ducimus quasi quos alias officiis
        praesentium temporibus. Deserunt?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[This is demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ66S.jpg)

Comment: Attach the code as well.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the pictures to touch the edges of the screen? If so, you can give them a class and add the following to the CSS for that class: "margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;".

Comment: No, I want that pictures touch edges, same demo pics